# Displaying R code using officer package

Tags: r, ms-word, officer

I've just started learning how to make reproducible research documents using R. The officer package looks pretty amazing. I've managed to make a Word document, but feel like I'm struggling to understand exactly how to use the software. Currently, I'm trying to figure out how to display R code. Just the code itself, or perhaps the code plus the output it generates.

Below is some simple R code.

How would I go about printing this in a mono-spaced format like courier? Would it be best to do this by setting something up in a template Word document? Or is this a simple task where it would make more sense to do it using package functions? If so, which ones? I've looked at functions like ftext and fp_text but don't seem to be finding a solution. I also noticed that there was something called pot in ReporteRs, but that doesn't seem to apply in the case of the updated officer package.

Also, what if I wanted the code to display in a gray box like what you see with rmarkdown in RStudio? Is that more a matter of seeting something up in a Word template?

```
###################################################
#### Example: Hyalurise in Vitreous Hemorrhage ####
###################################################

connection <- textConnection(
"
101  32 1 A 3  .   102  20 1 A 4 10   103 -52 0 A 3  .
104   4 0 A 4  .   105  24 1 A 4 52   106  41 1 A 3  .
107  32 0 A 4 12   108  32 1 A 4  .   109  25 0 A 3  .
110 -10 1 A 3  .   111   8 0 A 3  .   112  32 1 A 4  .
113 -52 0 A 4 38   114  45 1 A 3 36   115 -14 0 A 4  .
116   6 1 A 3  .   117 -52 1 A 4  .   118   9 0 A 4 28
119  13 1 A 3  .   120  36 0 A 4  .   121   6 1 A 4  .
122 -42 0 A 4  .   123  44 1 A 3 28   124 -52 0 A 3  .
125  23 1 A 4  .   126  30 1 A 3  .   127  16 0 A 3  .
128   2 1 A 3  .   129  21 0 A 3  6   130  26 1 A 4  .
131   8 0 A 3  .   132  46 1 A 4 18   133  21 1 A 4  .
134  14 1 A 3  .   135 -52 0 A 3  .   136 -24 1 A 3  .
137 -22 0 A 3  .   138 -35 0 A 3  .   139  19 1 A 3  .
140  24 1 A 4 20   141  31 1 A 3 12   142  28 0 A 4  .
143 -52 0 A 4 34   144 -52 1 A 3  .   145  35 0 A 3  .
146  40 1 A 4  .   147   4 0 A 3  .   148   7 1 A 4 24
149  -2 0 A 4  .   150  16 1 A 4  .   151  36 1 A 3  4
152  12 0 A 3  .   153  28 1 A 3  .   154  48 0 A 3 42
155 -38 1 A 3  .   156   9 1 A 3  .   157  11 0 A 3  .
158  20 0 A 4  .   159  30 1 A 4  .   160   6 1 A 4  .
201 -15 0 B 3  .   202  -4 1 B 3  .   203  10 1 B 4  .
204  10 0 B 4  .   205   8 0 B 3  .   206  11 1 B 3  .
207 -52 1 B 4  .   208  12 1 B 3  .   209  20 0 B 3  .
210  46 1 B 4  .   211  32 0 B 4 44   212  10 1 B 3  .
213  42 0 B 3  .   214  31 1 B 4 20   215   4 1 B 4  .
216 -24 0 B 3  .   217  20 1 B 3 33   218  16 0 B 3  .
219   2 1 B 3  .   220  25 1 B 4  .   221  11 0 B 4  .
222 -52 0 B 4  .   223  20 1 B 4  .   224   9 1 B 3  .
225  22 1 B 3  .   226  23 1 B 3  .   227  11 0 B 3  .
228  13 1 B 3  .   229  -7 0 B 4  .   230   8 1 B 4  .
231  37 1 B 4  .   232  32 0 B 4 26   233  24 1 B 3 10
234 -52 1 B 4  .   235  20 0 B 4  .   236  34 0 B 4  .
237  27 1 B 3  .   301  10 1 C 3  .   302 -10 0 C 4  8
303  32 1 C 4  .   304  14 1 C 4 20   305  24 0 C 3  .
306  14 1 C 4  .   307  36 0 C 3  .   308 -52 0 C 3  .
309   7 1 C 3  .   310   6 0 C 4  .   311   5 1 C 3  .
312   9 1 C 3  .   313  12 1 C 4  .   314  21 0 C 3  .
315  10 1 C 3  .   316  26 0 C 4 36   317 -52 1 C 4  .
318  10 1 C 3  .   319  27 0 C 4 12   320   5 1 C 3  .
321  34 1 C 3 16   322  14 0 C 4  .   323   6 1 C 3  .
324  22 1 C 4  .   325  45 0 C 4 12   326  16 0 C 3  .
327  15 1 C 3 30   328  33 0 C 4 22   329  20 1 C 3  .
330 -52 1 C 3 30   331   5 0 C 4  .   332  10 1 C 3  .
333  16 0 C 3  .   334  -2 1 C 4  .   335  17 0 C 4  .
336  16 0 C 4  .   337  16 1 C 3  .   338  33 1 C 3 20
339  24 0 C 3 11   340  12 1 C 3  .   341  27 1 C 4 18
342   2 1 C 4  .   343  -6 0 C 4  .   344 -20 1 C 4  .
345  14 0 C 3  .   346   3 1 C 3  .
"
)

vitclear <- data.frame(scan(
  connection,
  na.strings = ".",
  list(
    PAT = 0,
    RSPTIM = 0,
    TRT = 0,
    CENTER = "",
    DENS = 0,
    INFTIM = 0
  )
))

# RSPTIM = time (wks) from randomization to response (censored if negative)
# TRT    = 1 for Hyalurise, TRT = 0 for Saline
# CENTER = study center (A, B, or C)
# DENS   = 3, 4 for Grade 3 or 4, respectively
# INFTIM = time (wks) from randomization to onset of infection complications

vitclear$STATUS <- with(vitclear, ifelse(RSPTIM > 0, 1, 0))
vitclear$RSPTIM <- with(vitclear, abs(RSPTIM))
vitclear
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler just to use RMarkdown to produce a Word file, as it sounds like you're creating a Word file rather than editing one?

Comment: Ultimately want to be able to show code, plus text, plus complex tables in a single document. My impression is that support for Word tables in RMarkdown isn't very strong. For example, there's kable for making Word tables but it is purposely designed to be simple and therefore doesn't have a lot of sophisticated functionality. kableExtra adds functionality, but doesn't seem to support Word tables.  It's possible I think to integrate flextable into RMarkdown but that requires having pandoc >= 2.0 when RStudio is designed to work with < 2.0. Might try that route but it seems a bit painful.

Comment: My thought was also `flextable` with RMarkdown, but it sounds like that'll be awkward, too.